# MERN Stack - Field is missing when posting a new document to MongoDB from frontend

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, schema, mern

After making a connection to a MongoDB, my get and post routes are working on the express backend and my JSON data is hosted on Heroku. But when I made a form on my React frontend the post request was successful except the field "genre" is missing. I've double checked the form and I've console logged the newBook the form creates and the "genre" field is there. But when I visit the page for the book I created there is no genre property rendered, no genre in the object that console logs when you visit the page, and the document in MongoDB and on my Heroku backend is missing "genre"

As I said above, making the post request from the backend works fine. When I insert a document using a query and try not giving the "genre" field a key value pair it fails to post because "genre" is set to required in the schema. And of course that means it posts fine from the backend when "genre" is included.

An important piece of information is that "genre" was a field I added to the schema a little after making connections initially. But I don't know that should matter because the schema defined in App Services on MongoDB has "genre" included.

Here is the method I use on the frontend that gets called when my form is submitted

```
const createBook = async (book) => {
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(book),
    });
    getBooks();
  };
```

Here is the form

```
const Create = ({ createBook }) => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [newBook, setNewBook] = useState({
    title: "",
    author: "",
    cover: "",
    year: "",
    overview: "",
    genre: "",
    price: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewBook({
      ...newBook,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    createBook(newBook);
    console.log(newBook)
    setNewBook({
      title: "",
      author: "",
      cover: "",
      year: "",
      overview: "",
      genre: "",
      price: "",
    });
    navigate("/")
  };

  return (
    <div className="create-form">
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={newBook.title} name="title" placeholder="title" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="text" value={newBook.author} name="author" placeholder="author" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="text" value={newBook.cover} name="cover" placeholder="cover (URL)" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="number" value={newBook.year} name="year" placeholder="year" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="text" value={newBook.overview} name="overview" placeholder="overview" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="text" value={newBook.genre} name="genre" placeholder="genre" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="number" value={newBook.price} name="price" placeholder="price" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Book"/>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "title cannot be empty"],
    },
    author: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "author cannot be empty"],
    },
    cover: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "cover cannot be empty"],
    },
    year: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "year cannot be empty"],
    },
    overview: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "overview cannot be empty"],
    },
    genre: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "genre cannot be empty"],
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      min: [0, "price cannot be negative"],
      required: [true, "price cannot be empty"],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Book = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
module.exports = Book;
```

This is what console logs when the [book is created by the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9NrR.png)

This is what console logs when you visit that books show route [after it has been posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XFuG.png)

This is the matching JSON data for the new book [on the Heroku api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znFSU.png)

Below is a query I ran with Node.js to insert a couple documents to MongoDB and it worked perfectly and the genre field was there. So the problem must be coming from the form on the frontend.

```
const books = [
  {
    title: "Shutter Island",
    author: "Dennis Lehane",
    cover:
      "http://prodimage.images-bn.com/pimages/9780061898815_p0_v3_s1200x630.jpg",
    year: 2003,
    overview:
      "In 1954, widower U.S. Marshal Edward 'Teddy' Daniels and his new partner, Chuck Aule, go on a ferry boat to Shutter Island, the home of Ashecliffe Hospital for the criminally insane, to investigate the disappearance of a patient, Rachel Solando (who was incarcerated for drowning her three children).",
    genre: "Mystery",
    price: 7.99,
  },
  {
    title: "Hamlet",
    author: "William Shakespeare",
    cover:
      "https://www.memoriapress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Hamlet-Student-Cover-Saddle.jpg",
    year: 1603,
    overview:
      "The ghost of the King of Denmark tells his son Hamlet to avenge his murder by killing the new king, Hamlet's uncle. Hamlet feigns madness, contemplates life and death, and seeks revenge. His uncle, fearing for his life, also devises plots to kill Hamlet.",
    genre: "Tragedy",
    price: 4.99,
  },
];

db.Book.insertMany(books, {
  ordered: false,
})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log("books inserted into mongo");
  });
```

Comment: Post has been edited with the Node query 

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! Had to just step away and think about all the connections in a mern build. Just commented out the code that connects my schema and exports it as a model then commited to github then pushed. Then I just commented it back in and made another commit and push and the model seemed to have updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).